# How to scan dynamo table in AWS console with OR condition?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Recently, I have started using `dynamo table` and coming from `SQL` background, I am little confused the way it works.

I want to know if it is possible to `scan the table` with `OR` condition? All I see is `AND` condition, like below.

[image]

i.e. Let's say my column name is `id` and I want to get results of multiple `ids` then how can I do that? I am pretty sure there has to be some way but I don't know that.

Comment: When you say you want to get results of multiple ids, do mean you want results where id is either equal to id1 or id2? Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LegacyConditionalParameters.ConditionalOperator.html

There is OR conditional operator like you wanted with Query instead of Scan.

Answer (score 0):

We can achive Scan with OR in filter expression through code.

Example:

```
ScanResult result = null;
            ScanRequest req = new ScanRequest();
            Map<String, AttributeValue> expressionAttributeValues = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
            expressionAttributeValues.put(":dateStr", new AttributeValue().withS(date));
            expressionAttributeValues.put(":subDate1", new AttributeValue().withS(subDate1));
            req.setTableName(emailEventNotifsTableName);
            req.withFilterExpression("(begins_with(LastUpdated, :dateStr) or begins_with(LastUpdated, :subDate1))")
                    .withExpressionAttributeValues(expressionAttributeValues);
            int count = 0;
            dailyStatsTotalRows = new ArrayList<Map<String, AttributeValue>>();
            do {
//              ctx.getLogger().log("(getEmailEventNotifsTableStats)Iterating no:" + (++count));
                if (result != null) {
                    req.setExclusiveStartKey(result.getLastEvaluatedKey());
                }
                result = getAmazonDynamoDBClient().scan(req);
                List<Map<String, AttributeValue>> rows = result.getItems();
                for (Map<String, AttributeValue> row : rows) {
                    String lastUpdated = row.get("LastUpdated").getS();
                    ...
                }
            } while (result.getLastEvaluatedKey() != null);
```